# GET htmlTextBoxFor value inside HTML table using javascript

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Issue not able to get @htmltextboxfor value and @HiddenFor value which is inside Html table on change event of @htmltextboxfor

```
  <table id="tbl"  style ="width:100%"  class="race-fields" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
     <tr>
       @{      
         for (int i = 0; i < Model.lists.Count; i++)
          {                     
           <tr class="EvenRow">
              <td  align="center" class="txtNo">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lists[i].No, new { style = "width:5em;" }) </td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].col1) </td>    
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].col2) </td>    
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].col3) </td>    
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].col4) </td>    
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].col5])                 

                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].VId)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].sessionId)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].HCode)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].TCode)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].mId)
                                </td>                                                  
         }   
       }
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In script

```
  $('.txtNo input[type="text"]').change(function () {
            var No = $('input[type="text"]').val();
            var lineid = $('#hiddenlineId').val();

            alert(No);
            alert(lineid);
            });
```

On change event is being triggered, but the value of HtmlTextBoxFor and HiddenFor are always showing the first row values.

HTML

```
        <td align="center" class="txtNo"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field txtNo must be a number." data-val-required="The No field is required." name="lists[1].No" style="width:5em;" type="text" value="0"> </td>
        <td>5 </td>    
        <td>XXX </td>    
        <td>G </td>    
        <td>9 </td>    
        <td>ABC               

                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field VId must be a number." data-val-required="The VId field is required." name="lists[1].VId" type="hidden" value="217">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field sessionId must be a number." data-val-required="The sessionId field is required." name="lists[1].sessionId" type="hidden" value="1">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HCode must be a number." data-val-required="The HCode field is required." name="lists[1].HCode" type="hidden" value="873186">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TCode must be a number." data-val-required="The TCode field is required." name="lists[1].TCode" type="hidden" value="384505">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MId must be a number." data-val-required="The MId field is required." name="lists[1].MId" type="hidden" value="859489">
                <input name="lists[1].col1" type="hidden" value="5">
                <input name="lists[1].col2" type="hidden" value="XXX">
                <input name="lists[1].col3" type="hidden" value="G">
                <input name="lists[1].col4" type="hidden" value="9">
                <input name="lists[1].col5" type="hidden" value="ABC">          </td>
```

I assume its pretty silly , but being new to javascript. I am not able to find a solution. Please help
Many Thanks

Comment: <td  align="center" class="txtNo">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lists[i].No, new { style = "width:5em;" }) </td>              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].Age) </td>    
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].Name)  
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].LineId)
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].col2Id)
         </td>

Comment: <tr>
 <td align="center" class="No"><input name="lists[1].No"  type="text" value="0"> </td>
 <td>5 </td>    
 <td>XXX </td>    
 <td>G </td>    
 <td>9 </td>    
 <td>A       <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LineId must be a number." data-val-required="The LineId field is required." name="lists[1].LineId" type="hidden" value="217">
  <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field sessionId must be a number." data-val-required="The sessionId field is required." name="lists[1].sessionId" type="hidden" value="1">  
.....
 </td>
</tr>

Comment: There is no element having class as `txtNo`

Comment: <tr> <td align="center" class="txtNo"><input name="lists[1].No" type="text" value="0"> </td> <td>5 </td> <td>XXX </td> <td>G </td> <td>9 </td> <td>A <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LineId must be a number." data-val-required="The LineId field is required." name="lists[1].LineId" type="hidden" value="217"> <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field sessionId must be a number." data-val-required="The sessionId field is required." name="lists[1].sessionId" type="hidden" value="1"> ..... </td> </tr>

Comment: the first td element class= txtNo

Comment: Edit your question instead..

Comment: Edited.. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it shows first row values since you have multiple `rows` there. You need to fetch it using `$(this)` and `$(this).next()` as below:

```
$('.txtNo input[type="text"]').change(function () {
      var No = $(this).val(); //fetches from the current element
      var lineid = $(this).next().val(); //fetches its next element's value
      alert(No);
      alert(lineid);
});
```

> **Note -** `HiddenField ids` are duplicate here which is not correct. I would suggest to remove that as `@Html.HiddenFor` will create `id` for you

**Update**

You can also refer to `next element` with its type as below so that it targets correct `element`

```
var lineid = $(this).next("input[type='hidden']").val();
```

**Update 2**

```
$('.txtNo input[type="text"]').change(function () {
      var No = $(this).val(); //fetches from the current element
      var lineid = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='hidden']").val(); 
      //fetches hidden element's value which comes under its row
      alert(No);
      alert(lineid);
});
```

Comment: May be `next( "input[type="hidden"]" )`

Comment: @RayonDabre.. Not necessarily if this is the structure, but yea still your point is valid..

Comment: Hi.. htmltextboxfor is returning correct now. But the hiddenfor is returning undefined value. Actually its not the next element. Please see      <td  align="center" class="txtNo">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lists[i].No, new { style = "width:5em;" }) </td>              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].Age) </td>    
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lists[i].Name)  
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].LineId)
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lists[i].col2Id)
         </td>

Comment: See the above answer.. I have written it under **Update 2**

Comment: No probs.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Hi.. just a followup question. How can I set the value to hiddenfor inside td element using juery?  <td> @html.hiddenfor(m => m.col1)    @html.hiddenfor(m => m.col2)  @html.hiddenfor(m => m.col3 , new { @class = "hdnflg"}) </td>  ... Need to set value of hdnflg using juery.

Comment: no sorry. its assigning for all the rows.. It should be assigned to the rows only where the change is made.

Comment: You need to point to correct row.. Please google on that.. otherwise this comment part will simply grow up.. :)

Comment: something like  `$(this).closest('tr').find('.hdnflg').val('yourvalue')`